# Terraform create users

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to get terraform to create users for me other than the specified admin and also add them to sudoers to allow my ansible scripts to then run without requiring a sudo login. Optionally, if I could just allow my admin to login and not require sudo passowrd that would work as well since I can add the users I need via ansible.

I have attempted the only option I could find with my feeble googling skills. The option is to add a provisioner to my azurerm_virtual_machine resource that runs the following via remote-exec:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
        "useradd myuser && echo myuser:password123 | /usr/sbin/chpasswd",
        "chmod +w /etc/sudoers && echo \"myuser ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL\" >> /etc/sudoers && chmod -w /etc/sudoers",
    ]
    connection {
        user = "myadmin"
        agent = false
    }
    on_failure = "continue"
}
```

It says that it has successfully run however when I ssh to one of the boxes I provisioned these changes have not taken place. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: should you put this step to [paker](https://www.packer.io/) if you don't need `ec2-user`   to be root and manage the first admin account by yourself, more than in terraform?

Comment: Yeah this is definitely a software provisioning problem and not an infrastructure provisioning problem.

Comment: Thanks but we do not have the greenlight to use packer. So it sounds to me like terraform has the ability to create the admin user and add their key but can't elevate the admin user to passwordless auth? That's fine if it is the case. I can accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

USERNAME=$1 # sudo non-root username here

# Create user and immediately expire password to force a change on login
useradd --create-home --shell "/bin/bash" --groups sudo "${USERNAME}"
passwd --delete "${USERNAME}"
chage --lastday 0 "${USERNAME}"

# Create SSH directory for sudo user and move keys over
home_directory="$(eval echo ~${USERNAME})"
mkdir --parents "${home_directory}/.ssh"
cp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys "${home_directory}/.ssh"
chmod 0700 "${home_directory}/.ssh"
chmod 0600 "${home_directory}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
chown --recursive "${USERNAME}":"${USERNAME}" "${home_directory}/.ssh"

# Disable root SSH login with password
sed --in-place 's/^PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# if sshd -t -q; then systemctl restart sshd fi
```